# Primary Domain in Sub Folder Not Redirecting URLs WITHOUT Trailing Slash

Tags: .htaccess

I have a primary domain that I have stored in a sub-folder by intention. I have an issue when trailing slashes are **not** used.

When I try the following URL, for example, without the trailign slash:

http://www.myprimarydomain.com/test

It gets redirected to the true path:

http://www.myprimarydomain.com/www.myprimarydomain.com/test/

How can I prevent the true path from showing when **not** using a trailing slash?

I have the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www.myprimarydomain.com/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.myprimarydomain.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Hope this helps anyone in the future:

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ http://www.myprimarydomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myprimarydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myprimarydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myprimarydomain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/www.myprimarydomain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.myprimarydomain.com/$1 [L]
```